# New template file does not load category-specific post

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have 2 Files:

```
index.php
newStuff.php
```

I want to get all posts with one specific category with this Code:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1000000000,
    'cat' => '',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
);

$q = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $q->have_posts() ) { 

    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {

        $q->the_post();

        if (get_the_category( $id )[0]->name == "Sportprojekte") {

        }
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. I duplicated `index.php` into new `newStuff.php`, but the new file generates all posts.
2. Why does CSS stylesheet not showing up in the head?

Comment: Is that code just a part of `newstuff.php` or is it the entire file? I notice you don't set the category you wanted, you just specified `''`. Are you aware of the `category.php` template and category archives? For example you could visit `/category/foobar` and it would list all posts in the foobar category? And you could use the `category-foobar.php` template to change how it looks? Keep in mind that if you want to change what WP pulls in, you should use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the main query. Don't throw it away and create a new query in the template

Comment: This is the Code for the ```newstuff.php``` and the ```index.php``` file.

In the ```index.php``` file everything i want to get loadet, gets loadet but in the ```newstuff.php``` file, everything gets loaded but those 2 files have the same code and use the same ```header.php``` File

Comment: `index.php` is the fallback template, it should have a standard main post loop, otherwise all pages will show the same thing regardless of the URL. You're also missing a lot of the normal stuff from a template, like `get_header` and `get_footer`, and you might be missing stuff from `header.php` and `footer.php` too. I'd recommend instead of building everything from scratch that you use a starter theme such as underscores which has  all the needed function calls already present, but lacks any CSS